# RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same error when inception_v3 model

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am new to ComputerVision. I am trying to use inception_v3 for image classification on binary image dataset. I see following error

```
Epoch: 1 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-822a36ffbce7> in <module>
     12         total+=labels.size(0)
     13         images=images.cuda()
---> 14         output,aux1,aux2=model(images)
     15         aux1_loss=criterion(aux1, labels)
     16         aux2_loss=criterion(aux2, labels)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    457                             weight, bias, self.stride,
    458                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
--> 459         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
    460                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    461 

RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same
```

I have tried updating the image to image.cuda(), but haven't been successful so far

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    print("Epoch: %d "%(epoch+1))
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    running_correct = 0.0
    total=0
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader):
        images,labels=data
        images=images.to(device)
        labels=labels.to(device)
        total+=labels.size(0)
        output,aux1,aux2=model(images)
        aux1_loss=criterion(aux1, labels)
        aux2_loss=criterion(aux2, labels)
        output_loss = criterion(output, labels)
        loss = output_loss + 0.3*(aux1_loss + aux2_loss)
        running_loss += loss.item() * output.size(0)
        pred = output.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
        running_correct+=pred.eq(labels.view_as(pred)).sum().item()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        traning_accuracy = 100. * running_correct / len(train_loader.dataset)`
```

Answer (score 0):

The error, "Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same", means the input is in GPU and the model is in CPU. Need to use 'model.to(device)' so both are in GPU.